# JAWS doesn't read the text properly

Tags: accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I am trying to develop an accessible website with JAWS and FF but I couldn't find a way to make the screen reader not to read the codes.

I have tried using `<span></span>` but still it reads the codes.

For example I did this:
`<header><span role="heading">Hi</span></header>` and JAWS instead of reading "Hi" it says "page has one heading and no links. JAWS heading level 2 Hi."
and then when I move between browser tabs and return to the tab which I'm working on it says "Frame. Hi heading level 2"

So I'm wondering, is there a way to make JAWS reads what's on the screen only? Do I have to use AJAX or something?

NOTE: This is my first time to deal with accessibility, so I don't know where I went wrong and what should I do.

Comment: JAWS is designed to read the headings. There is a difference between `<p>hi</p>` and `<h2>hi</h2>`. Someone who can't see cannot tell the difference unless it reads out "heading level 2".